# Does typeorm raw sql query support IN clause

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I know we can use IN clause through querybuilder as:

```
await manager.getRepository(ReportEntity).createQueryBuilder()
                        .select('id')
                        .where('job_id IN (:...ids)',{ids:query_data[i].array_agg})
                        .getRawAndEntities()
```

Is it possible to do the same in a raw sql query? If yes, how do I pass parameters to IN clause
in a raw query?

If I want to do it like this:

```
await manager.query("select id from report where job_id IN (:...ids)",[{ids:['d8add1db-41fe-4e2d-b287-037fc22f1d29','a07497b7-1a94-482a-988c-1e2dcf6059c6']}])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
await manager.query(
    'SELECT id from report where job_id = ANY($1)',
    [['d8add1db-41fe-4e2d-b287-037fc22f1d29', 'a07497b7-1a94-482a-988c-1e2dcf6059c6']]
)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that's true

Comment: sqlite doesn't support "any", is there any way to make "in" work?